# Spring Integration polling inbound-channel-adapter on multiple servers

Tags: java, spring, oracle, mongodb, spring-integration

We have a Spring Integration application which is polling a `mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter` like so:

```
<int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter channel="n2s.mongoResults"
                                     collection-name="entities"
                                     query="{_id: {$regex: 'mpl/objectives'}})">
    <!-- Run every 15 minutes -->
    <int:poller fixed-rate="900000"/>
</int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Everything works fine. However, this application is deployed to a cluster and so multiple servers are running the same poller. We'd like to coordinate these servers such that only one runs the pipeline.

Of course, the servers don't know about each other, so we probably need to coordinate them through a locking mechanism in a database. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

### Notes:

We have access to both a MongoDB database and an Oracle database in this workflow. From the perspective of the workflow, it makes more sense to lock on the Oracle database.

It's fine if all server execute the polling step and then one server locks to actually process the records, if that's easier to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

You could use distributed locking tool like like Zookeeper.  Another alternative would be to change from a simple fixed trigger to a scheduling framework like Quartz which will ensure that the job only executes on a single node.

> It's fine if all server execute the polling step and then one server
>   locks to actually process the records, if that's easier to achieve.

Yea that's what I would do.  I think it's by far the easiest approach.  See [this post for details on how to do locking with Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627609/is-there-an-equivalent-to-sp-getapplock-sp-releaseapplock-in-oracle).

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, including:

Set `auto-startup="false"` and use some management tool to monitor the servers and ensure that exactly one adapter is running (you can use a `control-bus` or JMX to start/stop the adapter.

Run the application in SpringXD containers; set the module count for the source (containing the mongo adapter) and the XD admin will make sure an instance is running. It uses Zookeeper to manage state.

Use a distributed lock to ensure only one instance processes messages. Spring Integration itself comes with a `RedisLockRegistry` for such things or you can use any distributed lock mechanism.